# what is the fastest way to insert data into snowflake db table

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple `.csv.gz` files (each greater than 10GB) that need to be parsed - multiple rows are read to create one row insertion. The approach I'm taking is as follows:

1. read `.csv.gz` file
2. save soon-to-be-inserted rows into a buffer
3. if there is enough data in the buffer, perform multirow insertion to database table

Now snowflake limits maximum number of expressions to 16384. I've been running this for about a day but the speed at which it is inserting is very slow. I am using sqlalchemy to do this:

```py
url = "snowflake://<my snowflake url>"
engine = create_engine(url)
savedvalues = []
with pd.read_csv(datapath, header=0, chunksize=10**6) as reader:
  for chunk in reader:
    for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
      """
      <parsing data>
      """
      savedvalues.append(<parsed values>)
      if(len(savedvalues) > 16384):
        stmt = mytable.insert().values(savedvalues)
        with engine.connect() as conn:
          conn.execute(stmt)
        savedvalues = []
```

Is there a faster way to insert data into snowflake database tables?

I'm looking into `COPY INTO <table>` operation but not sure if this is truly faster than what I'm doing right now.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Using a bulk loading technique will almost always be faster - so use COPY INTO to get the data into Snowflake and then transform it as necessary use Snowflake’s native data transformation capabilities (SQL etc)

Comment: @NickW is `COPY INTO` the fastest way to get data into snowflake?

Comment: Yes, it is the fastest way to load large volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article describing a Python multithreaded approach to bulk loading into Snowflake [Zero to Snowflake: Multi-Threaded Bulk Loading with Python](https://interworks.com/blog/2020/03/04/zero-to-snowflake-multi-threaded-bulk-loading-with-python/). Also note to optimize the number of parallel operations for a load, Snowflake [recommends](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html#file-sizing-best-practices-and-limitations) data files roughly 100-250 MB (or larger) in size compressed.